# cant get the param route angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the [param] from url, and get some information throw a service with this param, and then (ONLY then) go to another page.

Chome URL: http://localhost:4200/login/asd

appmodule:

```
{ path: 'login/:token', component: AppComponent},
```

appcomponent.ts

```
ngOnInit() {

this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.usr = params['token']; 
  console.log(this.usr); //THIS KEEP GETTING UNDEFINED

});
}
```

That usr keeps getting undefined, dont know why...
Some idea? Thanks.

I tryied things like this:

```
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  if (!params['token']) { 
    console.log('NO token'); //GOES HERE EVERYTIME
     }
  this.token = params['token'];
  console.log(this.token);
});
```

It gets out in 'NO token' every single time..
Something wrong with the url maybe?

Comment: Cannot match any routes when I try that.

Comment: you have private route: ActivatedRoute in the constructor right? just to make sure

Comment: Yes sir I have: private route: ActivatedRoute

Comment: Please, test this url, just to be sure: http://localhost:4200/login/40

Comment: Same result Sir. Keep getting undefined. I dont understand why.. I used params in other places and works just fine..

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz page?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7s47c1

Comment: What are you expecting it to be? And if you look at the array in the debugger, is it just that particular key, or the whole array that is undefined?

Comment: The particular key. It supposed that if I write login/something, that key will be 'something'. But is always undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another question opened that describes your issue. This is related to `ActivatedRoute` state outside of a`router-outlet`, in your case I believe you don't have it.

I did a test in stackbliz where you can see it working with `router-outlet`, but to do this I had to change the router path to another component(The `AppComponent` is the root component, so I did not use it).

Here is the stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izk361

And here much more info about this problem.

[Angular 2 Activatedroute params not working in Service or outside <router-outlet>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40375888/6061376)

Comment: YES SR! You were right. 
For some reason the params dont work outside the router-outlet.

I move the login to other component, and get the params correctly.

Thank you!